# Work title - author/creator format convention

Tags: discussion, formatting

In an answer I am writing **Who Can Replace a Man?** by **Brian Aldiss**

Should there be a formatting convention for title of a piece of work and its creator?

Answer (score 6):

The normal convention is to italicise the titles of books, and to put the titles of shorter works that have not been published separately in double quotes. I don't see any reason to use a different convention here.

Comment: This is also what's used in most citation systems such as APA or MLA.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really think that we need some specific convention for this. Besides, it would be really hard to enforce.

Some common sense formatting, like italicizing work title, should work fine.

Also, I'd strongly encourage providing links to Wikipedia, imdb or similar sites on titles or author names. Yeah, I know... We can always right-click find on Google, but this is nicer.